# DPDK 19.11.10: UDP checksum hardware offload for 1500Bytes is correct but UDP checksum hardware offload for 9000Bytes (JUMBO FRAME) is incorrect

Tags: c, udp, intel, checksum, dpdk

I am working on DPDK 19.11.10 with intel NIC X710.

I am trying to calculate UDP checksum by offloading to hardware. UDP checksum is correct if packet size is 1500Bytes and UDP checksum is incorrect if packet size is 9000Bytes(JUMBO FRAME).

Here is my code:

```
   /*Port configuration*/
   rxmode = {
      .max_rx_pkt_len = 9614,
      .offloads = (DEV_RX_OFFLOAD_JUMBO_FRAME),
   }

   txmode = {
      .offloads = (DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_IPV4_CKSUM |
      DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_UDP_CKSUM | DEV_TX_OFFLOAD_TCP_CKSUM),
   }

   /* mb is mbuf packet to transmit */
   mb->ol_flags = PKT_TX_IPV4 | PKT_TX_IP_CKSUM | PKT_TX_UDP_CKSUM;
   mb->l2_len = sizeof(struct ether_hdr);
   mb->l3_len = sizeof(struct ipv4_hdr);
```

These are the flags I have used.

why I am seeing incorrect checksum for Jumbo frame?